# Nginx does not load css files (Django)

Tags: css, django, nginx, web-deployment

I made a new project in Django. On my local Computer everything is working just fine, so i tried to make it public. I used [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) as the host. I found 2 Tutorials to publish a Django Project on a DigitalOcean VPS. One is for Security and one is for publishing.

Django security Tutorial: [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04)

Django project publishing: [Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

After i followed the Tutorials everything worked fine except one thing. All files (Images, JS) are loaded correctly except the static css files, which is really strange. I think it is an Nginx problem. I am new to Nginx, so i don't know what to do. I tried a few Stackoverflow Questions and searched for this problem a lot, but I can't figure out what to do. The css files are located in a subfolder of a folder called static.
[Image of the static files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rowwq.jpg)

static files settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 142.93.100.9;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
       root /home/djangodeploy/bhitweb2;
    }

    location /media/  {
       root /home/djangodeploy/bhitweb2;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/djangodeploy/bhitweb2/bhitweb2.sock;
    }
}
```

CSS file URL: 142.93.100.9/static/css/form.css

CSS error:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML template link to stylesheets:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}/" />
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You end up with `Not Found` error ? Are you sure js files are correctly loaded from Nginx ? It could be loaded from your browser cache.

Comment: @TonyEight Yes i get a 404 error when i try to access the css file link in the HTML. Javascript files are loaded correctly. I also thought it could be a Browser cache problem, so i cleared the cache, but this does not work either.

Comment: Can you provide an example of URL for those not found CSS files ? And a snippet of your template code to see how you insert them.

Comment: @TonyEight Of course. I added them to my question.

Comment: If javascript files are served fine, and are in the same directory as css '/static/' then the problem shouldn't be your configuration, but something in your folder structure or missing files.

Comment: You have an error on your url `href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}*/*" />`. That backlash is not right

Comment: You are showing your local folder structure, what about the server?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I deleted the wrong */*, but it did not work.

Comment: @guillermochamorro The folder structure I uploded is the one from the server. It is a screenshot from filezilla. Furthermore I'd like to say, that all the css files I need are in the correct folder (static/css).

Comment: @DominikN so you can view the css files there? What about the permissions of the folder?

Comment: @guillermochamorro I have never looked up the permissions of a folder before in filezilla, but under public rights, read and execute are checked. write is not checked, but I think that should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at [your static files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rowwq.jpg), it looks empty. So, going back to your static definition in `settings.py`, I see `STATICFILES_DIR = '/home/djangodeploy/bhitweb2/static'`.

From what I know, the correct setting name is `STATICFILES_DIRS`, which is not a `string` but an iterable like so :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

You can find it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS).

I guess when you call `python manage.py collectstatic`, static admin files are the only one fetched.

The way you set things up seems to mixup `STATIC_ROOT` (which is where `collectstatic` stores your static files and which is the path you should serve via Nginx) with `STATICFILES_DIRS` (which is where `collectstatic` is supposed to fetch your **additional** - as mentioned in the docs - static files from).

You should try to put your coded static files in a `static` folder inside your app folder. Then, get rid of the `STATICFILES_DIRS` declaration and let Django find your static files automatically (Django does it through `STATICFILES_FINDER` - [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders)) when you call `collectstatic`.

**UPDATE**

Something is off with your Nginx conf. Both location `/static/` and `/media/` point to the same directory.

Try to also change it like this :

```
location /static/ {
   alias /home/djangodeploy/bhitweb2/static;
}

location /media/  {
   alias /home/djangodeploy/bhitweb2/media;
}
```

Then restart Nginx. Run `collecstatic` again.

Comment: I already tried this. I put STATICFILES_DIRS in the settings.py because i found a tutorial online and i thought this would probably work. All the ststic files(images, js, css)  are already in the correct folder. when i used collectstatic the STATICFILES_DIRS line was not in settings.py. However i deleted the line anyways.

Comment: I tried this, but now none of the files (media and static files) are loaded. I only have the functionality and HTML now. I did exactly what you said. Should I change my Nginx settings again?

Comment: I edited my reply because of a mistype (`alias` vs. `root` directive)... Anyways...

Still a few things to check :

First, make sure Nginx have access rights to those directory (**www-data** is Nginx default user). Then, make sure you restarted Nginx after editing the configuration file with `sudo service nginx restart`.

Comment: I tried what you said, but when I change those things all the files aren't loading again (no Images, no JS, no CSS).

Comment: Can you check your Nginx logs ? `sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log`

Comment: There are a lot of errors. This is the last one I got: 2018/08/10 14:51:41 [error] 27178#27178: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/form.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 212.95.7.8, server: 142.93.100.9, request: "GET /static/css/form.css HTTP/1.1", host: "142.93.100.9", referrer: "http://142.93.100.9/accounts/login/"

Comment: @DominikN this link works http://142.93.100.9/static/computer.jpg, shouldn't the image be on the /media/ path?

Comment: @chamorro no this image is a static file. i use this image for the design of my signup and login template.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have another `server` running (maybe the **default** nginx virtual host). As you set `listen 80;` I guess both virtual hosts definitions point to **port 80**.

Your app *HTTP requests* (especially thoses for your *static files*) end up being handle by this **default** virtual host.
This **default** virtual host for nginx has its `ROOT_DIRECTORY` set to `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.

This is why you have this kind of errors :

```
2018/08/10 14:51:41 [error] 27178#27178: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/css/form.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 212.95.7.8, server: 142.93.100.9, request: "GET /static/css/form.css HTTP/1.1"
```

**Solution 1**

You just have to disable this **default** virtual host. Look for all enabled `sites` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo service nginx restart
```

**Solution 2**

Add a `servername` directive (with the FQDN you want to use for your *Django* project) so nginx can seperate your app *HTTP requests* from those that should really go to the **default** virtual host.

Comment: How am I able to disable the default server? I went to the directory and found 2 shortcuts in this folder. My Projectname and the default server you were talking about. Am I supposed the delete this default shortcut to disable the default server?

Comment: You can disable this **default** `site` by deleting the file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. Do not worry, it is safe since this file is only a symbolic link to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`. You will be able to activate it back with a simple call to `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. In both cases, do not forget to restart nginx.

Comment: I am sorry to say, that this did not work either. I think I should probably change the host and try to deploy it there.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Do you have the same errors ? What did you find in nginx error log ?